# Prepend Div Collection With No ID

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to prepend the first Div in a collection of Divs with the same class but no ID in an HTML document with javascript. Their parent also doesn't have an ID.

```
<div class="shiftsListParent">
<div class="shiftsList2"></div>
<div class="shiftsList2"></div>
</div>
```

I'm looking to end up with a result that looks like

```
<div class="shiftsListParent">
<div class="shiftsList2">New Div Here</div>
<div class="shiftsList2"></div>
<div class="shiftsList2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the above, you've got something called `.shiftsListParent` followed by a couple of `.shiftsList2` elements, but the "parent" *isn't* the parent of those. Which seems odd.

Comment: Yep you were correct, just fixed it to illustrate better.

Comment: It doesn't change the answer, however, unless you have multiple `.shiftsListParent` elements and want to work *within* one that isn't the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.querySelector` will return the first element matching a CSS selector, and then you can use [`insertBefore`](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-node-insertbefore) on that element's parent:

```
var div = document.querySelector(".shiftsList2");
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML = "New Div Here";
div.parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, div);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var div = document.querySelector(".shiftsList2");
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML = "New Div Here";
div.parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, div);
```

```html
<div class="shiftsListParent">
<div class="shiftsList2">original first</div>
<div class="shiftsList2">original second</div>
</div>
```